# python 3.6 and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

Здравствуйте. Нужно скомпилировать программу python v3.6 c GUI tkinter. Использую cx_freeze, вроде компилица, но программа не запускается, выдаёт эту ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код в файлах connectBD.py и start.py на позиции 3, `from tkinter import*` если использовать просто `import tkinter`, выдаёт ту же самую ошибку
Использую код setup.py следующий.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("start.py", base=base)])
```

пробовал использовать код из этой статьи https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-tkinter-to-exe-with-cx-freeze/ программа даже не компилируется, выдаёт это:

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    executables = executables
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
 line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in
setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in
run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in
run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line
 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in r
un_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in
run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
 line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.p
y", line 621, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.p
y", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludePackage(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 653, in IncludePackage
    module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 310, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 403, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 416, in _LoadModule
    namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 485, in _LoadPackage
    self._LoadModule(name, fp, path, info, deferredImports, parent)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 463, in _LoadModule
    self._RunHook("load", module.name, module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py
", line 536, in _RunHook
    method(self, *args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks.py"
, line 612, in load_tkinter
    tclSourceDir = os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'
```

Тоже самое выдают подобные скрипты. Что делать?

Comment: "вроде компилица" - python интерпретируемый язык.
ModuleNotFoundError, сама ошибка говорит о себе,
что касается KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY', то в словаре os.environ по ключу "TCL_LIBRARY" отсутствует значение, поэтому os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]  выкидывает данную ошибку

Comment: @Fedir Alifirenko Ошибку при компиляции исправил, но теперь возникло это... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617084/python-3-6-0-and-tkinter-part-2

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте из build_exe_options убрать "tkinter" из excludes.
И разберитесь зачем нужна переменная окружения 'TCL_LIBRARY'.