# ImportError при запуске cx_Freeze-скомпилированной tkinter программы

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, cx-freeze

Здравствуйте. Использую python v3.6.0 64 bit, GUI tkinter, windows тоже 64 bit. Скомпилировал программу с помощью cx_freeze, но при запуске выдаёт эту ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код setup файла этот:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6"
base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("start.py", base=base, icon="clienticon.ico")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "SeaofBTC-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","matplotlib"], "include_files":["clienticon.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Sea of BTC trading application",
    executables = executables
    )
```

использовал эту статью, https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-tkinter-to-exe-with-cx-freeze/ помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Текст ошибки лучше как текст, а не картинку публиковать, чтобы помочь другим людям с той же проблемой найти этот вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Всё ошибку исправил, скопировал четыре файлы

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll;
C:\Program Files\Python36\DLLs\tk86tg.dll;
C:\Program Files\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll;
C:\Program Files\Python36\DLLs\tcl86tg.dll;
```

Скрипт setup.py следующий:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import matplotlib
import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6"
# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}
sys.argv.append("build")
filename = "start.py"
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
setup(
    name = "Unick Locker",
    version = "2.0",
    description = "a GUI app that helps you securing your files and data with many functions",
    executables = [Executable(filename, base=base)])
```